# Invalid CSS after " ": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, webpack-4, sass-loader

I am trying out Vue with SASS but I run into a problem ben using npm run build. I use webpack sass-loader. Can anyone help me out here? I suspect the problem is somewhere in my webpack config, but I can not find the problem.

Error output:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-42a765dc","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/Header.vue
Module build failed: 
<template>
^
      Invalid CSS after " ": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
      in /Users/rafrasenberg/webconexus/src/wcxwebsite/src/components/Header.vue (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-42a765dc","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/Header.vue 4:14-355
 @ ./src/components/Header.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
```

The header.vue file:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">UA</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <router-link tag='li' :to="{ name: 'home'}">
          <a>Home</a>
        </router-link>
        <router-link tag='li' :to="{ name: 'cutecat'}">
          <a>CuteCat</a>
        </router-link>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data () {
    return {
}
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="sass">
  @import './../assets/styles/colors'
header
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-around
    align-items: center
    background-color: $green
    border-bottom: 2px solid darken($green, 30%)
    color: $white
    div#logo
      font-size: 200%
      width: 33%
    nav
      flex-grow: 2
      ul
        padding: 0
        display: flex
        justify-content: space-around
        list-style: none
        a
          text-decoration: none
          color: $white
</style>
```

And now my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
  new BundleTracker({filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
  new WriteFilePlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
           use: [
               "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
               "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
               "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
           ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve('src')
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

My package.json with all my installed dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "wcxwebsite",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "webconexus <raf@webconexus.nl>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.2-beta",
    "webpack-dev-server": ">=3.1.11",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style scoped lang="sass">
  @import './../assets/styles/colors'
header
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-around
    align-items: center
    background-color: $green
    border-bottom: 2px solid darken($green, 30%)
    color: $white
    div#logo
      font-size: 200%
      width: 33%
    nav
      flex-grow: 2
      ul
        padding: 0
        display: flex
        justify-content: space-around
        list-style: none
        a
          text-decoration: none
          color: $white
</style>
```

**Webpack.config.js**

Add extra rule to it

```
  {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          indentedSyntax: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Well this worked, but why can't I use the sass syntax without the semicolons? It solves the problem but now I am using scss

Comment: @RafRasenberg https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass-vs-scss have a look into this

Comment: @RafRasenberg try adding this into your webpack config file 

`{
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              indentedSyntax: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }`

Comment: You should remove the first part then or state that it is an extra solution. When you edit the webpack.config rule you don't need to change the sass to scss

Comment: Forget that you already changed it. Thanks I approved your anwser!

Answer (score 3):

If this helps anyone, I got this error because of a wrong indent:

```
@import ...

  .class
  ...
```

When it should be:

```
@import ...

.class
  ...
```